# How to delete realm list in Realm Database

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I'm having a Realm class called `Sale`. I had a list of objects called `allSales` for Sale class. Now I want to delete some objects in `Sale` Realm class.

```
    RealmResults<Sale> allSales = realm.where(Sale.class).findAll();
    RealmList<Sale> toBeDeleted = new RealmList<Sale>();

    for(Sale sale : allSales){
        String salesDate = sale.getSaleDate();
        if(salesDate.equals("01-01-2017")) {
            toBeDeleted.add(realm.copyToRealm(sale));
        }
    }

    realm.beginTransaction();
    toBeDeleted.clear();
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

The data was not cleared in `Sale` class instead `toBeDeleted` list only cleared.

Comment: I can't able to use 'deleteFromRealm' function.

Comment: I'm using Realm database version 0.87.4

Comment: why are you using 0.87.4 when the latest version is 3.1.4 (btw you are looking for `clear()`, and the docs https://realm.io/docs/java/0.87.4/api/io/realm/RealmList.html )

Comment: While there are several suggestions below, I think that the real answer is "update your Realm".  That version is way old.

Comment: Sure I'll update my version soon. Currently I need delete few object inside realm db. Please help me to delete

Comment: You can easily delete those object by updating, and then following the directions in any of the answers below.  If for some reason you don't want to do that, please use the ancient documentation here: https://realm.io/docs/java/0.87.4/#deletion

Answer (score 3):

You can use `RealmList.deleteFromRealm()`/`RealmList.deleteAllFromRealm()` 
to remove items from both the list and Realm.
See the methods in API docs here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmList.html

Comment: I got error "cannot resolve symbol deleteFromRealm".

Answer (score 0):

You have to call this method from realm transaction...

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                        saleRalmList.deleteLastFromRealm();// use to delete all

                                        //**OR** use in for loop to delete perticulr record as a location
                                        saleRalmList.deleteFromRealm(location);

                                    }
                                });
```